# No module named django-extensions

Tags: python, django

I need help.I am trying to run a django project that requires django-extensions module.i did pip install django-extensions and also in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....
    'django_extensions',
)
```

but when i try to run the server it says "Import Error,No module named django-extensions.What could be the problem ?

Comment: `django_extensions`, not `django-extensions`

Comment: @Belter had the same mistake somehow)

Answer (score 0):

Have you look to install this: 
apt-get install python-django-extensions